# Some facebook friends' birthdays returning as null but I have the correct API permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm tring to get **my friends' birthdays** in my app and some of them are **null**. I thought that those people don't have a birthday set, but **they actually do**.

My fql query is:

`SELECT uid,name,birthday_date FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 from friend where uid1=me())`

The birthdays are also null when I request `/me/friends?fields=birthday`

My access token has the `friends_birthday` permission set.

I also tried with `birthday` instead of `birthday_date` in the FQL query. Same result.

I imagine that this happens because they opted out somehow, but I don't know how.

Is there an alternate solution to actually get their birthdays from facebook?

Comment: is there any way now to get those users birthday

Comment: @MaherIsmaail no, there isn't

Comment: thanks ... but why parse stopped if it,s null , even if i do this : 
if(object.getString("birthday") != null) {  }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's also possible to remove the ability of apps to access your data when your friends use them, this option will prevent the current session user from seeing some information about their friends via the API, even if that information is accessible on Facebook.com

This setting is in the privacy settings, at https://www.facebook.com/settings/?tab=privacy, under Ads, Apps and Websites -> 'How people bring your info to apps they use' and looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

{edit} you can test this for yourself with test users, it's the most likely reason assuming the birthdays are visible to you in the frontend

Comment: I know this is kind of old... but I'm wondering if you know of a way to detect these specific privacy settings of an authenticated users friend?  i.e / usercase :  so the app can present some sort of notification that the particular facebook friend has it set to not allow access to their data... so the authed user knows it's not a bug in your app?

Comment: No, there is no API for returning these privacy settings

Answer (score 0):

These people might have set their Birthdays visible to only themselves or only some restricted friends. This is an option available if we try to edit our Birthday by its side. That can cause it is not available to your query by app.